# Cisco WLC 5508 - Cannot ping Redundancy Mgmt Ip

Tags: cisco, wlc, aironet

I have a couple of Cisco WLC 5508 systems.  They are set up as follows:

- System A: (Mgmt IP 172.16.1.4/24) (Redundancy Mgmt Ip 172.16.1.5)  SSO Mode ENABLED
- System B: (Mgmt IP 172.16.1.15/24) (Redundancy Mgmt Ip 172.16.1.16) SSO Mode DISABLED

FWIW, I have a Cat5e cable run between the two redundant ports.

My problem is that I can ping all addresses above, except 172.16.1.16.  My question is whether this is expected or not.  If I'm not supposed to be able to ping 172.16.1.16, then under what conditions should I be able to ping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redundancy management address is only pingable if the controller is configured in SSO mode.